# How to create fields group as accordions?

Tags: entities, nodes, navigation

Hello Drupal community,

I am trying to create a group of fields with an accordion, so that it can be visible/unvisible with a simple clic on the title of the field's group.

Does anyone know how to do it ? Or know a module that does it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module is great for that usage.

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.

Comment: That sounds good, but how I don't see any accordion widget, how do I implement that functionality?